# Pass JVM arguments to Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, jvm-arguments

We are running our Apache Beam code in Google cloud dataflow, we need to pass some JVM argument to our program. We found links related to Execution Parameters, but nothing related to JVM arguments. How to pass the JVM arguments to  Google Cloud dataflow?

Comment: Given that DataFlow is a managed service, you really can't directly send arguments to the JVM instance, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you just want to pass arguments to your program you can simply extend your options object with whatever you want.